# R: compute penalty matrix of basis functions?

Tags: r

Given a set of spline basis functions `f_1, ..., f_n`, the associated penalty matrix is the matrix where element `i, j` is the integral of the product of the second derivatives`f''_i * f''_j`, where the integral is taken over some appropiate domain.

See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline#Cubic_spline_definition

How can this penalty matrix be computed in R for some appropiate choices of basis functions?

I am not asking for how to get the matrix for arbitrary basis functions: R offers many standard functions to compute some specific  basis functions (like splineDesign, bs, ns, poly, etc). My question is specifically how to get a penalty matrix for such specific functions.

Any of them will do.